# Member Field Mapping in Cartthrob and Profile Edit

Tags: cartthrob, profile-edit

I am having problems mapping member data fields with the Cartthrob / ProfileEdit combo. As I understood it with both of these modules installed I should be able to go to the 'Members' tab in CT and map the fields to the relevant fields in my chosen  profile channel.

I am sure in the past this is exactly what I have done, however now when I go to the 'Members' tab and click on the Member Custom Fields drop downs to map the fields their are no options available.

Have I just imagined this or is that how it is supposed to work.. going a little crazy!

Cartthrob 2.4
ProfileEdit 1.1.7
ExpressionEngine 2.7.2

Edit:

I have just tested this by installing some old versions:

EE 2.5.3
CT 2.2.7
P:E 1.1.7

The CT member fields can be mapped to P:E, but as soon as I upgrade CT to:

EE 2.5.3
CT 2.3.9.1
P:E 1.1.7

CT's member fields cannot be mapped to P:E. So it seems somewhere between CT 2.2.7 and 2.3.9.1 it lost the ability to map. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: A few things to run through...
- always good to update to the latest versions of CE and PE
- have you created custom fields in your PE Members channel?

Comment: Hi Bluedreamer, I reported the issues to Chris and he confirmed them as bugs.

Comment: Kenny, did Chris suggest when the bug would be fixed?  My situation is the same as yours, but I installed PE after CE. I'm using EE 2.5.2, CT 2.4 and PE 1.1.8. It seems from your OM, an EE upgrade to 2.7.x will not help. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing yet I am afraid. Bonnie said they would start work last Monday and I arranged a follow up Skype call for Tuesday but it was unanswered. I haven't been able to get a reply since then.